# Masterpage not opening (Xamarin Forms)

Tags: forms, xamarin, navigation, master-pages

I got a problem when i open masterpage. Basically i am using the default masterdetail app that xamarin forms creates when you choose MasterDetail App on a new project. I have a custom navigation bar and when i click the button it shows the masterpage. I achieved it with this:

```
public ICommand OpenMenuCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(() =>
            {
                var mainPage = (Application.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage).CurrentPage;
                (mainPage as MasterDetailPage).IsPresented = true;
            });
        }
    }
```

When it opens and i try to select a page to navigate to , i get null in the Root Page (you can see in the following code):

```
public partial class MenuPage : ContentPage
{
    MainPage RootPage { get => Application.Current.MainPage as MainPage; }
    List<HomeMenuItem> menuItems;
    public MenuPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        menuItems = new List<HomeMenuItem>
        {
            new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.CLIENTS, Title="CLIENTS" },
            new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.WIZARD, Title="WIZARD" },
            new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.SETTINGS, Title="SETTINGS" },
            new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.GUIDES, Title="GUIDES AND TEMPLATES" },
            new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.HELP, Title="HELP" },
            new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.LOGOUT, Title="LOGOUT" }
        };

        ListViewMenu.ItemsSource = menuItems;

        ListViewMenu.SelectedItem = menuItems[0];
        ListViewMenu.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.SelectedItem == null)
                return;

            var id = (int)((HomeMenuItem)e.SelectedItem).Id;
            await RootPage.NavigateFromMenu(id);
        };
    }
}
```

The Root Page here is a MainPage but the MainPage in App.cs is Navigation Page (had to do it in order to navigate with the custom navigation bar).
It works good with the default forms Navigation Bar.

How can i do it so i can call the master page from custom navigation bar, and also navigate ?

P.S. I didnt post all the code of mainpage etc since it is the default code that xamarin forms creates when you select to create a masterdetail app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Di  you solved the issue？I use the simialr code and it works fine

Comment: @MonkeySteve no i didnt, are you calling the masterpage from a custom button like me ? Cause i know the default navigationbar hamburger menu works fine. 

Please let me see your code.